# Weirdness with hats in chat!

Tags: bug, chat, winter-bash-2013

There are a couple of weird issues with hats in chat:

[image]

[image]

Refreshing fixes it but after a period of time (normally when the tab containing the chat room hasn't been used in a while) it reoccurs again.

Comment: I haven't noticed the first issue, but as far as the second issue goes, are you using a non-stable channel Chrome? I get repaint issues in chat pretty often that are caused by that, including one earlier like what you have in the second screenshot.

Comment: Nope, this is with stable chrome - second screenshot is from another person in the bridge but I've had that multiple times today as well

Comment: The second issue should be fixed by now - do a hard refresh. The former is not neccessarily a bug depending on where the user has set his hat to appear

Comment: The first one's "hat" shows as over the top of his avatar in the AU main chat room, just in the regulators room that it showed incorrectly. Refresh has fixed them both (for now?)!

Comment: Both of these were fixed hours ago -- are you sure you have seen this with current JavaScript?

Comment: @balpha I have just forced a full refresh of all of my chat windows, I'll let you know if it happens again